# Remove old repository-URLs from artifacts which are no longer in use

Tags: nexus, apache-karaf, artifacts

I have several services deployed in my Karaf-container. Most of them have multiple repository-URLs. I want to remove the old URLs, but it seems that this isn´t possible if the old artifacts are no longer in my Nexus repository.

Exp: I´m using Service XYZ with Version 25.0, but still have the repository-URLs for the versions 22.0,23.0 and 24.0. These versions are already deleted in my Nexus repository, but Karaf won´t uninstall/remove them because it can´t find them. But why is Karaf looking at all? I just want to remove the old stuff. It seems like I have to reset the container because in its current state it´s not possible to add or remove any features, Karaf always complains about not finding the old artifacts.

Is there any way to delete these entries manually, e.g. some file where Karaf keeps track of the old repository-URLs?

Answer (score 0):

In a maven repository it is not a good idea to remove a version or an artifact. Anything that is published to maven must stay there. Maven creates copies of artifacts in the local repository. For releases it will never check again in nexus once a local copy is found.

So karaf simply does not expect that a released artifact ever goes away. 
Why do you delete these old versions anyway?